How to Prepare Data for U-Net Model Training with .tif Images
I'm new to image segmentation and trying to train a U-Net model. I have a dataset consisting of .tif satellite images and their corresponding annotations. Here is a sample of my data:
    file_name   annotations
train_33.tif    [{'class': 'field', 'segmentation': [51.333, 0...
train_16.tif    [{'class': 'field', 'segmentation': [1010.8136...
train_26.tif    [{'class': 'field', 'segmentation': [947.59490...

Could someone guide me on how to prepare this data for training a U-Net model? Specifically:
How should I handle the .tif satellite images and annotations?
What preprocessing steps are necessary?
How should the annotations be formatted to work with U-Net?
Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
